# Dynamic content using ItextSharp inside a PDF form

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, adobe

I am creating some PDF forms to fill in my current project. But I can not figure out how to populate the content dynamically, like adding more rows to a table and spacing content below it.

**Example:**

This is the template to add data, using Adobe Acrobat to create a PDF form and ItextSharp to fill it out.

[image: Example - PDF form template]

And this is the pdf form after receiving the content

[image]

Is this possible when using the Acrobat form and ItextSharp? If not, what way do you think i should do to reach this result?

Answer (score 0):

Good to see that you use itextsharp for your use-case. Note that itextsharp is actually iText 5 which is already end-of-life. You better use iText 7 in your software.

I am a part of iText team as well and there is actually a product just for your use-case. It is called DITO and you can configure repeating rows in tables, which is what you need in your use-case. I am sure you can do it with itextsharp as well, however my answer is to show to how to do it properly without re-inventing the wheel. In DITO, you will design your PDF template, similar to what you did in Acrobat to create your form. Now the catch here is that you define your data-binding to the elements you want in a browser-based editor and once your are done with your design, the only thing is to send your data to this template using DITO backend SDK. Let me show you an example JSON data.

```
{
"first_name": "Lucius",
"last_name": "Malfoy",
"email": "malfoy@hogwarts.com",
"address": "Abra Cedavra\nTo the att. of L. Malfoy\nWiltshire\nEngland",
"items": [
    {"item": "Commercial Invisibility Cloak License .NET", "price": "6800", "quantity": "1"},
    {"item": "Updates and Support Commercial Invisibility Cloak .NET", "price": "666", "quantity": "1"},
    {"item": "Commercial Non-Production House Elf", "price": "3140", "quantity": "1"},
    {"item": "Updates and Support Commercial Non-Production House Elf", "price": "152", "quantity": "1"},
    {"item": "Nimbus 2001", "price": "5640", "quantity": "13"},
    {"item": "Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find them", "price": "28", "quantity": "1"}
    ]
}
```

As you can see there are 6 items in the "items" node. This basically tells that the row in the table will repeat 6 times. Now, if this would have contained 200 items, the table would repeat 200 times, possible going over different pages with headers and footers.

The one you made doesn't work just because you design a "static" form. Dynamic forms could also be done in PDF using XFA technology which is already deprecated in the latest PDF standard.

If you want to know more about it, I would suggest to contact to iText and they will guide you on how to achieve what you want.